# USB3 HDD write speed Debian 11 vs Ubuntu 22 (ESXi 7.0U3 VMs)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, usb-storage, esxi

I have two VMs running on an ESXi 7.0U3g host.

Both VMs are installed on an NVMe datastore (FYI for comparison below, note "usbspeed" vs "nvmespeed" tests), and have identical configuration:

- CPU: 8
- Memory: 16GB
- SCSI Controller: LSI Logic Parallel
- USB Controller: USB 3.1

VM #1: Debian 11.4.0 (5.10.0-18-amd64)

```
# dmesg | grep usb
[237086.992370] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[237087.013420] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=264d, bcdDevice=30.12
[237087.013422] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[237087.013423] usb 2-1: Product: easystore 264D
[237087.013424] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[237087.013425] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: [redacted]
[237087.046318] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[237087.046483] scsi host33: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[237087.046547] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[237087.048081] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas

# lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M

# lspci | grep -i usb
13:00.0 USB controller: VMware USB3 xHCI 1.0 Controller

# dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/easystore/usbspeed bs=1M count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 6.84469 s, 157 MB/s

# dd if=/dev/zero of=/nvmespeed bs=1M count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 0.664862 s, 1.6 GB/s

# sysctl -a | grep -i dirty
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 10
vm.dirty_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000
vm.dirty_ratio = 20
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 500
vm.dirtytime_expire_seconds = 43200

# cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler
[mq-deadline] none
```

VM #2: Ubuntu 22.04.1 (5.15.0-43-generic)

```
# dmesg | grep usb
[ 8175.488648] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 8175.509805] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=264d, bcdDevice=30.12
[ 8175.509808] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 8175.509810] usb 2-1: Product: easystore 264D
[ 8175.509811] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[ 8175.509812] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: [redacted]
[ 8175.540057] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 8175.540532] scsi host33: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[ 8175.541089] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 8175.542779] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas

# lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M

# lspci | grep -i usb
0b:00.0 USB controller: VMware USB3 xHCI 1.0 Controller

# dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/easystore/usbspeed bs=1M count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 0.567066 s, 1.9 GB/s

# dd if=/dev/zero of=/nvmespeed bs=1M count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 0.636782 s, 1.7 GB/s

# sysctl -a | grep -i dirty
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 10
vm.dirty_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000
vm.dirty_ratio = 20
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 500
vm.dirtytime_expire_seconds = 43200

# cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler
[mq-deadline] none
```

I've run the same tests multiple times and gotten similar results every time, so it's not like a one-time or cache related thing.

Why is Debian so much slower when writing to the USB3 disk?

- Edit 1: added output from `lsusb -t`
- Edit 2: added output from `lspci | grep -i usb`
- Edit 3: added output from `sysctl -a | grep -i dirty` as per comment from @gapsf
- Edit 4: added output from `cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler` as per comment from @gapsf

Comment: Make vm kernel parameters that begins with dirty* the same and compare again. https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html

Comment: Did you install guest drivers vmware-tools suited for both os?

Comment: @gapsf - Both VMs have appropriate vmware tools package installed. Also, running ``sysctl -a | grep -i dirty`` produces identical results across both VMs.

Comment: There is a bunch of usbcore kernel parameters

Comment: @gapsf, perhaps I don't know enough to keep up here... I had to google to figure out how to find the last ones. I ran ``sysctl -a | grep -i usb`` on both and got nothing.  Can't find any differences in vmx files that would seem to matter, either.

Comment: Compare io schedulers for your usb disk # cat /sys/block/.../queue/scheduler

Comment: Usbcore is a kernel commandline parameters. Skip it. Check schedulers

Comment: @gapsf both output exactly one line: ``[mq-deadline] none``

Comment: Did you sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches before each dd?

Comment: What you usb3 device is? It is very suspicios it is fast as 1.9 GB/s because if it external hdd 157MB/s is the real speed

Comment: Its write caching issue. dd is bad for tests. You shoud use direct write io with oflag=direct in dd command if version of dd support it

Comment: https://www.westerndigital.com/products/portable-drives/wd-easystore-desktop-usb-3-0-hdd#WDBAMA0080HBK-NESN. Per smartctl /dev/sdb: ``SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)``. It's a WD RED drive in a plastic shell.

Comment: As i wrote above it cant 1.9 GB/s by definition. Its write caching speed on ubuntu. Read above about dd flags

Comment: So you should ask yourself how is it possible write to hdd at 1.9 GBbyte/s while write speed of hdd is about 150-200 MBytes/s and over sata with maximum speed about 0.6 GByte/s